# ng-if (trying to implement if-else)

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please correct me if i am wrong, My understanding on ng-if directive was like if and else conditions if use multiple ng-if directives. So here in my code i am trying to show three divs
based on their presence in returned json inner object(metricList). But it's creating multiple divs for the same if-else which is wrong. Please suggest.

```
<div ng-repeat="p in profileData">
        <div>{{p.company}}</div> 
        <div>{{p.department}}</div>

        <div ng-repeat="emp in p.metricList">

            <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo100'">
              Devo100 if condition
            </div>

            <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo100'">

              Devo100 else condition

            </div>




            <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo101'">
              Devo101 if condition
            </div>
            <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo101'">
              Devo101 else condition

            </div>



            <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo102'">
              Devo102 if condition
            </div>
            <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo102'">
              Devo102 else condition
            </div>


                <hr>
```

my plunker code url

http://plnkr.co/edit/cfkJBD6ZIHYGCzKP4BtY

Comment: How can we discriminate between the three possible `else` conditions?  If something does not equal a value, it could be any other value, right?  How many actual divs do you want to render?

Comment: Your code does exactly what you described. Basically there's three "if-else"-blocks within each iteration. None of them (based on your Plunkr) got the `emp.Stat.Tag == 'DevoXXX'` condition truthy, which is why you only see the "else"-condition in place. Maybe you should explain a little more what you actually want to do.

Comment: `ng-if` doesn't have an `else`.  it affects the HTML element it exists on only, and renders the element if the condition is true, or does not render the element if the condition is false.   Each `ng-if` statement is independent.

Comment: Of note, none of the `if` conditions appear to be true for your sample data.

Comment: Nothing wrong with those if conditions. The HTML appeared to be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed your plunkr and created a fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/l3s2Rglq8Cokgxjgh7dQ?p=preview

Basically, what was wrong was that you're using

```
<div ng-repeat="emp in p.metricList"></div>
```

So you're immediately closing the div again, what you need is:

```
<div ng-repeat="emp in p.metricList">

  <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo100'">
    Devo100 if condition
  </div>

  <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo100'">
    Devo100 else condition
  </div>



  <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo101'">
    Devo101 if condition
  </div>
  <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo101'">
    Devo101 else condition
  </div>



  <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo102'">
    Devo102 if condition
  </div>
  <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo102'">
    Devo102 else condition
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note, as I've already mentioned at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15886, the code has more, possible, flaws such as the usage of `==` instead of `===`.

Answer (score 2):

**Observation :** You are using the conditions **`ng-if="....."`** outside the **`ng-repeat`**.

**Incorrect Code as per plnkr :** `<div ng-repeat="emp in p.metricList"></div>`

Here, you are closing the `ng-repeat` div(loop) immediately.

**Working DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.profileData = [];
  $scope.profileData.push(
      
         {
               ID: "1",
               metricList: [{"Value":0.003,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test0","Tag":"Devo100"}},
                             {"Value":0.004,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test1","Tag":"Devo101"}},
                             {"Value":0.005,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test2","Tag":"Devo102"}}],                  
               company: "MSDFT",
               department: "Sales"
              },
              {
               ID: "2",
               metricList: null,                  
               company: "MSDFT",
               department: "HR"
              },
            {
               ID: "3",
               metricList: [{"Value":0.003,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test0","Tag":"Devo100"}},
                             {"Value":0.004,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test1","Tag":"Devo101"}}],                  
               company: "MSDFT",
               department: "Development"
              },
             {
               ID: "4",
               metricList: [{"Value":0.1,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test2","Tag":"Devo102"}},
                             {"Value":0.25,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test1","Tag":"Devo101"}}],                  
               company: "MSDFT",
               department: "Finance"
              },
             {
               ID: "5",
               metricList: [{"Value":0.233,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test0","Tag":"Devo100"}}],                  
               company: "MSDFT",
               department: "Accounts"
              }
    
   );  
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="p in profileData">
  <div>{{p.company}}</div> 
  <div>{{p.department}}</div>
  
  <div ng-repeat="emp in p.metricList">
  
   <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo100'">
     Devo100 if condition
   </div>
   
   <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo100'">
     
     Devo100 else condition
     
   </div>
   
  
   
   
   <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo101'">
     Devo101 if condition
   </div>
   <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo101'">
     Devo101 else condition
     
   </div>
   
  
   
   <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag == 'Devo102'">
     Devo102 if condition
   </div>
   <div ng-if="emp.Stat.Tag != 'Devo102'">
     Devo102 else condition
   </div>
   
   
    <hr>
   
     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: It's a bit odd to add the exact same answer as mine, no ? :P